# Do I have to ID/KYC artists/suppliers if they've already been ID'd by the payment provider

Tags: australia, identification

I'm an Australian e-commerce store with international buyers, selling artworks by international artists.

**Question / TL;DR:**
If a vendor/supplier of an e-commerce store ID's themself to a payment service provider and the e-commerce store ID's themself to a payment service provider, if those two payment providers are in locations that recognize each others KYC obligations does this mean the e-commerce store doesn't need to ID/KYC the vendor/supplier directly?

**My confusion:**

Many companies collect the ID photos/selfies directly, however it seems the requirement is only for financial institutions, not companies like e-commerce stores who use those financial institutions.

Most payment providers have clear KYC requirements for marketplace platforms to onboard their users, however for non-marketplaces it's often mentioned that you can payout suppliers to 200+ countries within minutes etc but doesn't go into KYC obligations.

I'm not sure if the assumption is that marketplace vendors need to open a new payout account which requires ID and that suppliers already own a payout account for which they've completed KYC.

Also I'm not sure if there is a difference between the terms supplier, customer, store owner and vendor when it comes to KYC (if the artist is a vendor, I need onboard them with KYC on a marketplace, if they're a supplier I can just go ahead and pay them).

**Research -**
**AUSTRALIA:**

https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/C2021C00243

Part 1 - Introduction
4  Simplified outline

> The following is a simplified outline of this Act:
>
> A reporting entity is a financial institution, or other person, who
> provides designated services. (Designated services are listed in
> section 6.)
>
> A reporting entity must carry out a procedure to verify a customer’s
> identity before providing a designated service to the customer.
> However, in special cases, the procedure may be carried out after the
> provision of the designated service.
>
> ...

Section 6  Designated services

> For the purposes of this Act, the following tables define:
> (a)  the provision of a designated service; and
> (b)  the person (the customer) to whom the designated service is provided.
>
> Provision of a designated service in the capacity of account provider,
> opening an account, where the account provider is:
> (a) an ADI (Authorised Deposit-taking Institution); or
> (b) a bank; or
> (c) a building society; or
> (d) a credit union; or
> (e) a person specified in the AML/CTF Rules
>
> Customer of the designated service:
> the holder of the account

**Research -**
**US:**

https://www.irs.gov/businesses/international-businesses/list-of-approved-kyc-rules

> Revenue Procedure 2000-12PDF states that the IRS will not enter into a
> qualified intermediary (QI) withholding agreement that provides for
> the use of documentary evidence obtained under a country's
> know-your-customer rules if it has not received the know-your-customer
> practices and procedures for opening accounts and responses to 18
> specific questions listed in the revenue procedure.
>
> This document lists those countries that have submitted
> know-your-customer rules and those rules have been approved.
>
> ...

Australia is one of the countries listed who submitted approved rules.

**My conclusion:**

I'm not one of the financial entities listed in the legislation providing a designated service (ADI, bank, building society, credit union etc). It seems like the KYC requirement is specific to financial institutions not e-commerce stores which used those financial institutions. So I believe all I need to do is ask artists to open an account with one of *these* payment providers, tell me your account and I'll pay you. Of coarse I need to review who's products I allow to be sold however no need for my small business to get involved with the ID documents and KYC status?